# Keep attribute class consistent in TagLibs

Tags: grails, taglib

I am using a custom TagLib to format dates. From my view, I am passing a domain field into the TagLib like so:

```
<g:usDate value="${invoice.invoiceDate}" />
```

In this case the value goes into the TagLib with a type of Date. However, when I try to use the TagLib to format the contents of a field:

```
<g:textField name="invoiceDate" value="${g.usDate(value:"${invoice.invoiceDate}")}" />
```

the value goes into the TagLib as a type of GStringImpl. Is there a different syntax I can be using on the textField that passes the value as a Date so that I can use the same TagLib for both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inner quotes and `${}`:

```
<g:textField name="invoiceDate" value="${g.usDate(value:invoice.invoiceDate)}" />
```

This will pass the actual object `invoice.invoiceDate` to the taglib, rather than creating a GString containing the string representation of the object.

It's a little confusing but you need to remember that `${}` means different things in different places. As a tag attribute it says "the content inside the braces is a Groovy expression, evaluate it and pass the resulting value directly to the tag". But once you're inside a Groovy expression it has the normal GString meaning of "evaluate this expression and insert its `toString` representation into the GString".

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Ian for the answer and the additional explanation. Your solution works as advertised.